# How to replace the spaces with the number of spaces counted in the strings if the spaces is equal to 4 or more than 4 in c++ language?

Tags: replace, whitespace

Suppose you are given a text file that has been badly prepared for example, having more than one character spaces between words, lines in the text that are empty,
repeated sequence of characters, etc. Your tasks are to read this text file and perform some simple editing and then to write the result in a separate file. Below are the specific tasks you have to accomplish:

(i) Write a function compress() that replaces, in text lines, all sequences of four or more blanks by the characters $n$, where n is the number of blanks. What must be done if the character $ is found in the input text?. Store the result in a separate text file.

(ii) Write a function expand() that converts the text file created by compress() function above to re-produce the original text.

You may test your compress() and expand() functions for (i) & (ii)
with the following sample text file original-text.txt

1: ^^^^Suppose^you^are^given^with^a^text^^^^^^^^^^file^that^has^been^^^badly^^^

2: prepared^^^such^as^more^^^^than^one^character^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^spaces^^between

3: words,^^^lines^in^the^^^^text^^^^^^that^are^empty,^repeated^sequence^^^^^^^^

4: blanks^^^^^by^the^^^characters^^^^^$n$^^^^^,^where^^^n^is^the^number^of^blank

5: ^^^^^$^What^must^be^^^^^^done^if^^^the^character^$^is^found^in^the^input^text

6: ?.Storetheresultinaseparatetext^file^^^^^^.

7: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

8: Write^a^function^^^^^expand()^that^converts^^^^^^$n$^the^text^file^create.

Note the number at the beginning on each text line shown above is not part of the text file and character space(s) in the text file in the example above is represented by a ‘ˆ’ character (in the actual text file the space character ‘ ’ will be used).

Sample output of compress() function using the file original-text.txt as input:

1: $4$Suppose you are given with a text$10$file that has been badly

2: prepared such as more$4$than one character$16$spaces between

3: words, lines in the$4$text$6$that are empty, repeated sequence$8$

4: blanks$5$by the characters$5$$n$$5$, where n is the number of blank

5: $5$$ What must be$6$done if the character $ is found in the input text

6: ?.Storetheresultinaseparatetext file$6$.

7: $24$

8: Write a function$5$expand() that converts$6$$n$ the text file create.

The output of expand() function is as in the original-text.txt.

this is what I'm trying to do ..

```
int main()
{
    ifstream input("original-text.txt");

    //Read Data
    string data;
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        getline(input,data);
        cout << data << endl;
    }

    int i,n;
    n= 0;
    for( i = 0; data[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if( data[i] == ' ' )
            n++;

        cout << "$" << n << "$";
    }

    input.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not only did you do nothing but dump the assigned problem into the box, unless I'm missing something you didn't even bother to mention what language you're using.  Voting to close.

Comment: sorry, im new user and just dont know why i can't put the the code just now..